# Android SDK Manager stopped running

Tags: sdk

Earlier Android SDK Manager.exe was launched and I downloaded the necessary files. Now when I run the SDK Manager.exe the console application appears for a second  and then nothing happens. Operating system: Windows 7 x64 SP1. How to make it work like before?

Sorry for my English, it's not my native language.

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK Manager.exe is just launcher for %SDK_DIR%/tools/android.bat

But in last SDK update "android.bat" code was changed to simple

```
@echo off
echo The "android" command is no longer available.
echo For manual SDK and AVD management, please use Android Studio.
echo For command-line tools, use
echo tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat and tools\bin\avdmanager.bat
exit /b 1
```